# Emacs on Ubuntu: Function documentation lacks link to source code

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I use Emacs on Ubuntu at work.  One persistent annoyance has been that function documentation does not include a link to the function's source code.  For example, on my Ubuntu system the documentation for `find-file` begins:

> find-file is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

On my home machine, the same function is documented like this:

> find-file is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `files'.

Clicking on "files" will take me to the function's definition.

How can I get the standard, useful behavior on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't install the source by default, so there's nothing for it to point to.  You need to install the [`emacs23-el`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/emacs23-el) package.